# Is it accepable to repeat ask a question?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question on Stack Overflow, but accidentally posted all of the code, not just the broken bit. Is it acceptable to re-post the question with the right section of code?

Comment: Are you aware that you can edit posts?

Comment: I suppose you could flag your bad one for deletion, then re-post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's acceptable if the original has been deleted, but you want to avoid that at all costs.

Under your question, you should see the following:

[image]

You have a couple of options (in order of community's preference):

1. You can edit your question and remove the unnecessary code
2. You can delete your question if it doesn't have any upvoted answers and repost it
3. If it has upvoted answers, you can flag your post for moderator attention and explain your situation, then repost it **after your original has been deleted**

[image]

[image]

The second and third steps really shouldn't be necessary: just edit your post and fix the issues.

Comment: This is correct, of course. And you put the warning about doing the delete/repost right where it should be: at the very top here. For the flagging part; moderators will be *very reluctant* to delete a question that has upvoted answers, unless there are special circumstances (the question/answers are bad and really need to be removed, for example)